# Retaining state between Django views

Tags: django, state, kml

As a little backstory, I'm working on an application which pipes KML to googleearth based on packet data from a mesh network. Example:

UDP Packet ---> Django ORM to place organized data in DB ---> Django view to read the DB and return a KML representation of the packet data (gps, connections, etc) to Google Earth.

The problem here being that the DB rows tell a story and doing a query, or a series of queries, isn't enough to "paint a picture" of this mesh network. I need to retain some internal python structures and classes to maintain a "state" of the network between requests/responses.

Here is where I need help. Currently, to retain this "state", I use Django's low level cache API to store a class with unlimited timeout. And every request, I just retrieve that class from the cache, add to it's structures, and save it back to the cache. This seems to be working, and pretty well actually; but it doesn't feel right.

Maybe I should ditch Django and extend Python's BaseHTTP class to handle my requests/responses?

Maybe I should create a separate application to retain the "state" and Django pipes it request data through a socket?

I just feel like I'm misusing Django and being unsafe with crucial data. And help?

I know this is unconventional and a little crazy.

(Note: I'm currently using Django's ORM outside of a Django instance for the UDP socket listener, so I am aware I can use Django's environment outside of an instance.)

Comment: Sessions is a good suggestion, thanks! I guess I should have made it clear that I was asking for overall design decision advice, not really how to adapt Django to do what it's not really meant to. I'm prototyping my application without django and using basic Python CGI libs for google earth response/request handling; and it's working so far. I'll post an update with proper reasoning when I decide what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe I should ditch Django and extend Python's BaseHTTP class to handle my requests/responses?

Ditching Django for Python's BaseHTTP won't change the fact that HTTP is a stateless protocol and you want to add state to it. You are correct that storing state in the cache is somewhat volatile depending on the cache backend. It's possible you could switch this to the session instead of the cache.

> Maybe I should create a separate application to retain the "state" and Django pipes it request data through a socket?

Yes this seems like a viable option. Again HTTP is stateless so if you want state you need to persist it somewhere and the DB is another place you could store this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark! I believe in my case the DB is out of the question to store this state (you couldn't have known that though). There is just too much data to for this. Ideally these states would live in memory.

Comment: "Too much data" and "fit all into memory" don't really go together very well. There are plenty of other data stores you could use other than a relational database.

Comment: Ah yes, that did sounds a little oxymoronic. You've got me on the right step, I'm going to make this the right answer (I'll update my post when I decide on something).

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds like the kind of storage problem Redis and MongoDB are made to efficiently handle. You should be able to find a suitable data structure to keep track of your packet data and matching support for creating cheap, atomic updates to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! MongoDB is nice, I will admit. I do not think I have complex enough data to bring Redis into this since Django's low level cache is essential a key value store. I'm using the 'value' here to be a 'state' object. 

Now you've got me rethinking everything. ;)